# ui.grid row not able to select row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

```
$scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", Date:
     "01-1-2015",country:"india",address:"address"},
                 ];
$scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'myData',
    enableRowSelection:true,
};

<div flex>
<div class="gridStyle" ui.grid="gridOptions"> </div> 
</div flex>
```

I have angular version 1.3.15 and i have installed  angular ui-grid.
after running my app it shows grid but not able to select row

Comment: Are you using ng-grid 2.* or ui-grid(which is really ng-grid 3.0)?

Comment: im using "version": "3.0.0-rc.20"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<div class="gridStyle" ui.grid="gridOptions"> </div>
```

needs to be

```
<div class="gridStyle" ui-grid-selection ui-grid="gridOptions"> </div>
```

You also need to add the module ui.grid.selection to your dependencies. Be sure to keep your '.' and minuses straight. Sometimes it doesn't matter until it does.

See [UI-Grid Selection](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/210_selection) For more details

Comment: Gonna need to see the whole controller then. A plunker replication would be prefered

Comment: 'use strict';
angular.module('myAppApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http,$modal) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [];
     $scope.dataModel={
        event:[],
        modelObject:{}
    }
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", Date: "01-1-2015",country:"india",address:"address"},
                     ];
   $scope.mySelection=[]
    $scope.gridOptions = { 
        data: 'myData',      
    };  });

Comment: You need to add the ui.grid and ui.grid.selection to your module dependencies. angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.selection']);

Comment: it is working but my requirement is to select row on mouse click not using ccheckbox

Comment: You may be able to edit the grid API for a click event. Or you can also define you own template that uses ng-click for a function that selects the row as in the example provided in the answer